Как под домиком добавить текст "Home" (см фото)?
вот код прошу помочь!



.button-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(27, 133, 219);
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px,
    rgba(27, 133, 219, 0.5) 5px 10px 15px;
}

.button {
  outline: 0 !important;
  border: 0 !important;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
}

.icon {
  font-size: 20px;
}
<div class="button-container">
  <button class="button">
    <svg
      class="icon"
      stroke="currentColor"
      fill="currentColor"
      stroke-width="0"
      viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"
      height="1em"
      width="1em"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path
        d="M946.5 505L560.1 118.8l-25.9-25.9a31.5 31.5 0 0 0-44.4 0L77.5 505a63.9 63.9 0 0 0-18.8 46c.4 35.2 29.7 63.3 64.9 63.3h42.5V940h691.8V614.3h43.4c17.1 0 33.2-6.7 45.3-18.8a63.6 63.6 0 0 0 18.7-45.3c0-17-6.7-33.1-18.8-45.2zM568 868H456V664h112v204zm217.9-325.7V868H632V640c0-22.1-17.9-40-40-40H432c-22.1 0-40 17.9-40 40v228H238.1V542.3h-96l370-369.7 23.1 23.1L882 542.3h-96.1z"
      ></path>
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="button">
    <svg
      class="icon"
      stroke="currentColor"
      fill="none"
      stroke-width="2"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      aria-hidden="true"
      height="1em"
      width="1em"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
        d="M21 21l-6-6m2-5a7 7 0 11-14 0 7 7 0 0114 0z"
      ></path>
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="button">
    <svg
      class="icon"
      stroke="currentColor"
      fill="currentColor"
      stroke-width="0"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      height="1em"
      width="1em"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path
        d="M12 2.5a5.5 5.5 0 0 1 3.096 10.047 9.005 9.005 0 0 1 5.9 8.181.75.75 0 1 1-1.499.044 7.5 7.5 0 0 0-14.993 0 .75.75 0 0 1-1.5-.045 9.005 9.005 0 0 1 5.9-8.18A5.5 5.5 0 0 1 12 2.5ZM8 8a4 4 0 1 0 8 0 4 4 0 0 0-8 0Z"
      ></path>
    </svg>
  </button>

  <button class="button">
    <svg
      class="icon"
      stroke="currentColor"
      fill="none"
      stroke-width="2"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      stroke-linecap="round"
      stroke-linejoin="round"
      height="1em"
      width="1em"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <circle cx="9" cy="21" r="1"></circle>
      <circle cx="20" cy="21" r="1"></circle>
      <path
        d="M1 1h4l2.68 13.39a2 2 0 0 0 2 1.61h9.72a2 2 0 0 0 2-1.61L23 6H6"
      ></path>
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>




Достаточно для .button задать flex-direction: column и под самой svg написать нужный текст.


.button-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(27, 133, 219);
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px,
    rgba(27, 133, 219, 0.5) 5px 10px 15px;
}

.button {
  outline: 0 !important;
  border: 0 !important;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* added */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
}

.icon {
  font-size: 20px;
}
<div class="button-container">
  <button class="button">
    <svg
      class="icon"
      stroke="currentColor"
      fill="currentColor"
      stroke-width="0"
      viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"
      height="1em"
      width="1em"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path
        d="M946.5 505L560.1 118.8l-25.9-25.9a31.5 31.5 0 0 0-44.4 0L77.5 505a63.9 63.9 0 0 0-18.8 46c.4 35.2 29.7 63.3 64.9 63.3h42.5V940h691.8V614.3h43.4c17.1 0 33.2-6.7 45.3-18.8a63.6 63.6 0 0 0 18.7-45.3c0-17-6.7-33.1-18.8-45.2zM568 868H456V664h112v204zm217.9-325.7V868H632V640c0-22.1-17.9-40-40-40H432c-22.1 0-40 17.9-40 40v228H238.1V542.3h-96l370-369.7 23.1 23.1L882 542.3h-96.1z"
      ></path>
    </svg>
    
    Home
  </button>
  <button class="button">
    <svg
      class="icon"
      stroke="currentColor"
      fill="none"
      stroke-width="2"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      aria-hidden="true"
      height="1em"
      width="1em"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
        d="M21 21l-6-6m2-5a7 7 0 11-14 0 7 7 0 0114 0z"
      ></path>
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="button">
    <svg
      class="icon"
      stroke="currentColor"
      fill="currentColor"
      stroke-width="0"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      height="1em"
      width="1em"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path
        d="M12 2.5a5.5 5.5 0 0 1 3.096 10.047 9.005 9.005 0 0 1 5.9 8.181.75.75 0 1 1-1.499.044 7.5 7.5 0 0 0-14.993 0 .75.75 0 0 1-1.5-.045 9.005 9.005 0 0 1 5.9-8.18A5.5 5.5 0 0 1 12 2.5ZM8 8a4 4 0 1 0 8 0 4 4 0 0 0-8 0Z"
      ></path>
    </svg>
  </button>

  <button class="button">
    <svg
      class="icon"
      stroke="currentColor"
      fill="none"
      stroke-width="2"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      stroke-linecap="round"
      stroke-linejoin="round"
      height="1em"
      width="1em"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <circle cx="9" cy="21" r="1"></circle>
      <circle cx="20" cy="21" r="1"></circle>
      <path
        d="M1 1h4l2.68 13.39a2 2 0 0 0 2 1.61h9.72a2 2 0 0 0 2-1.61L23 6H6"
      ></path>
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>




Спасибо! благодарен

@Dima, если ответ решает ваш вопрос - нажмите на галочку слева от ответа.
